# R (macos 10.8.5), RcppArmadillo : can not find armadillo library or symbol _wrapper_ddot_

Tags: c++, c, r, rcpp, armadillo

Installing "RcppArmadillo" fails me badly and for some hours now, on "R"

```
R-2.3.1
```

and MACOS system 10.8.5 :

```
Darwin 12.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.6.0; xnu/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Armadillo (6.100.0) has been compiled and installed successfully.

This is the offender:

```
R> install.packages("RcppArmadillo", verbose=T)
```

compiles OK but fails to successfully load the package (as a build-time test). The output is this:

```
* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* checking LAPACK_LIBS: divide-and-conquer complex SVD available via R-supplied LAPACK
** libs
g++ -I/opt/local/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -arch x86_64 -framework System -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/.../usr/include -I/Users/.../usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I"/opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -arch x86_64 -framework System -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/.../usr/include -I/Users/.../usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
clang: warning: -framework System: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -framework System: 'linker' input unused
g++ -I/opt/local/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -arch x86_64 -framework System -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/.../usr/include -I/Users/.../usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I"/opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -arch x86_64 -framework System -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/.../usr/include -I/Users/.../usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
clang: warning: -framework System: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -framework System: 'linker' input unused
g++ -I/opt/local/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -arch x86_64 -framework System -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/.../usr/include -I/Users/.../usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I"/opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fPIC  -arch x86_64 -framework System -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/.../usr/include -I/Users/.../usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
clang: warning: -framework System: 'linker' input unused
clang: warning: -framework System: 'linker' input unused
g++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/local/R.framework/Resources/lib -arch x86_64 -framework System -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -L/opt/local/lib -L/Users/.../usr/lib -L/Users/.../usr/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/opt/local/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/opt/local/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -F/opt/local/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
  dlopen(/opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so, 6): Symbol not found: _wrapper_ddot_
  Referenced from: /opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/opt/local/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo’
```

So, in short, it requires symbol "_wrapper_ddot_" which it can not found.
But this symbol is in /opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.dylib which has been installed successfully. For example:

command:

```
nm /opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.dylib | grep _wrapper_ddot_
```

output:

```
/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.dylib
00000000000023e0 T _wrapper_ddot_
```

Then I create a ~/.R/Makevars to contain:

```
PKG_LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib -larmadillo
```

Trying to install again using:

```
R> install.packages("RcppArmadillo")
```

Compiles OK again but now it can not load the armadillo dylib and gives this error message:

```
...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/private/tmp/RtmpqEsodh/Rinst62b64deb7e7/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
  dlopen(/private/tmp/RtmpqEsodh/Rinst62b64deb7e7/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so, 6): Library not loaded: libarmadillo.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/RtmpqEsodh/Rinst62b64deb7e7/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed
```

I have even compiled the package manually skipping the tests and then installing. No! It always complains that it can not load the armadillo library or find the symbol "_wrapper_ddot_"

However, the (dependency) armadillo library is there:

```
ls -al /opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  5... /opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib
```

(and various symbolic links to it, e.g. 6.dylib and just dylib)

Setting ~/.R/Makevars to:

```
PKG_LIBS += -larmadillo
CFLAGS += ${PKG_LIBS}
CXXFLAGS += ${PKG_LIBS}
```

brings no good news from this front (and I am getting desperate now).

Finally, I have written a small c program to dlopen() the armadillo library (dylib). Depending on what open mode I use it succeeds or fails as follows:

```
trying : mode 2 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 2 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 1 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 1 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 8 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 8 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 4 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 4 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 18 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    error for mode 18 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'    err: Undefined error: 0
trying : mode 17 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    error for mode 17 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'    err: Undefined error: 0
trying : mode 24 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    error for mode 24 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'    err: Undefined error: 0
trying : mode 20 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    error for mode 20 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'    err: Undefined error: 0
trying : mode 130 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 130 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 129 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 129 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 136 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 136 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 132 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 132 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 258 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 258 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 257 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 257 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 264 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 264 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
trying : mode 260 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
    success: mode 260 and lib '/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib'
```

The C program to test-load the armadillo library using various modes is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(void){
    char lib[] = "/opt/local/lib/libarmadillo.6.10.0.dylib";
    int modes[] = {
        RTLD_NOW, RTLD_LAZY, RTLD_GLOBAL, RTLD_LOCAL,
        RTLD_NOW|RTLD_NOLOAD, RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_NOLOAD, RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NOLOAD, RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_NOLOAD,
        RTLD_NOW|RTLD_NODELETE, RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_NODELETE, RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NODELETE, RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_NODELETE,
        RTLD_NOW|RTLD_FIRST, RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_FIRST, RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_FIRST, RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_FIRST
    };


    for(int modeI=0;modeI<16;modeI++){
        int mode = modes[modeI];
        void    *ahandle;
        printf("trying : mode %d and lib '%s'\n", mode, lib);
        if( (ahandle=dlopen(lib, mode)) == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "\terror for mode %d and lib '%s'", mode, lib);
            printf("\terr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        } else {
            dlclose(ahandle);
            printf("\tsuccess: mode %d and lib '%s'\n", mode, lib);
        }
    }
}
```

The question:
Why is R not loading the armadillo library?
Is there an R equivalent to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Other packages installed work OK (about 30 packages).

Also, armadillo C++ program compiles and runs OK:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
  mat A = randu<mat>(4,5);
  mat B = randu<mat>(4,5);

  cout << A*trans(B) << endl;

  return 0;
  }
```

with

```
g++ -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib arma.c -larmadillo
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: What path does `otool -L /path/to/RcppArmadillo.so | grep libarmadillo` give you?

Comment: We do not link against `libarmadillo` in RcppArmadillo.

Comment: I suspect this is a OS X build tool issue, and have nothing to offer as I don't work on OS X.

Comment: Ok problem solved as per kevin's suggesion. See my comment below. Many thanks for RcppArmadillo, it is really useful for me.

Comment: `g++` version may be a cause to this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that RcppArmadillo bundles Armadillo (it's a header-only library), so client packages using `RcppArmadillo.h` will get the parts of `armadillo` that they need on compile -- explicitly linking to a pre-compiled `armadillo` library should be unnecessary.

`RcppArmadillo` does use pieces of `armadillo` (from its own included headers) in some compiled code (e.g. `fastLm`) and these should be discovered in `RcppArmadillo`'s own shared object file, `RcppArmadillo.so`.

On my OS X (El Capitan) machine, I see no `wrapper` prefix on the `ddot` symbol:

```
kevin:~/Library/R/3.2/library/RcppArmadillo/libs
$ nm RcppArmadillo.so | grep ddot
                 U _ddot_
```

There is a `#define`, `ARMA_USE_WRAPPER`, that seems to control this. The exported names chosen are configured at:

https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp#L46-L49

And used here:

https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp#L51-L57

I think you need to ensure that `#define` is unset. Is it possible you have it set / configured elsewhere?

Comment: Kevin your suggestion solved the problem. Thank you. I have changed "set(ARMA_USE_WRAPPER true)" to "set(ARMA_USE_WRAPPER false)" in file CMakeLists.txt in the top directory of armadillo-6.100.0

Comment: @bliako - You don't need to install Armadillo in order to use RcppArmadillo. In fact, the two installations are interfering with each other.

Comment: They are not interfering at all. I tend to have both the standard Debian/Ubuntu package for Armadillo installed as well as RcppArmadillo, and there is no interaction whatsoever.  This issue was "merely" a misconfiguration on the OP's part.  The R build system, when used as designed, works.

Comment: I already had armadillo installed on my system using macports (i will call it 'system armadillo'). Obviously it used the default "set(ARMA_USE_WRAPPER true)" setting at compile time. When I tried to install.packages("RcppArmadillo") in R-3.2.1 I got the aforementioned problem. Uninstalling system armadillo and then installing the RcppArmadillo in R works fine. In order to make both work, one needs to compile system armadillo using Kevin's suggestion. I have just confirmed now that by removing system armadillo, R installs RcppArmadillo with no complaints at all. They can coexist too.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 1/2 years the problem occured again and the solution is still valid and relevant. R-3.4.3 in OSX refuses to install bloody RcppArmadillo unless I remove armadillo system package (not R package) via `port uninstall armadillo` first.

So,

`port uninstall armadillo`

brothers